# Dictionary vs List

Tags: c#

The list in C# can be traversed by for, but is there a special reason why Dictionary can be referred to as a[0] with a declaration of <int, int> type, but not for for, but only with foreach? And why can the List be toured with the for repeat statement?

Answer (score 3):

If you refer to the [documentation for a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item?view=net-7.0), you can see that it declares an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/):

```cs
public T this[int index] { get; set; }
```

This allows us to access the elements of the list by index, e.g.:

```cs
int item = listOfInt[5]; // this will retrieve the 6th item in the list
```

To retrieve the item, the `get` method of the indexer is called and the index value 5 is passed in. This is how it knows which item you want.

Now, if you refer to the documentary for a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=net-7.0), you can see that it also declares an indexer:

```cs
public TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
```

But you'll note that this indexer is different: instead of taking an `int` value for `index`, it takes a dictionary key. This allows you to access items by key (e.g. `Person p = dictionaryOfPeople["Bob"];`).

Yes, you can declare multiple indexers that differ by the indexing argument (index or key in the previous examples), but this would essentially prevent using an indexer for `Dictionary<int, int>` because it would be ambiguous which indexer you were referring to: is it the index? is it the key? This is why such an indexer can't exist on a dictionary.

The reason `foreach` works is that it operates on types that implement an `IEnumerable` interface. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0)), so when we do a `foreach` over a dictionary our items are `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` objects. A `List<Person>` implements `IEnumerable<Person>` so when we do a `foreach` over this, our items are `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a `List` and `Dictionary` are different. A `List` is basically supposed to be a dynamic array, so it provides access by index like an array does but it also allows items to be added and removed. The point of a `Dictionary` is to access items by key rather than by index. If you declare the key type to be `int` then you can access a value by an `int` key but it's still a key, not an index. Indexes in a `List` start at zero and are sequential, while keys in a `Dictionary` can be any value of the specified type, so `int` keys in a `Dictionary` don't necessarily have to include zero and don't have to be sequential. An example of a use for a `Dictionary` would be a list of `Employee` objects keyed on an employee ID.